# PIVOT to pivot rows into columns dynamically

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have a table of customers and their purchase types and purchase notes on each row.

I want to pivot the purchase types and notes so that each row represents only 1 instance of the customer.

**Table**:

```
Customer ID  | Name | Purchase Type | Purchase Notes
-------------+------+---------------+---------------
1            | John | Furniture     | TextABC 
1            | John | Appliance     | TextDEF 
1            | John | Accessory     | TextGHI
```

**Objective**:

```
Customer ID  | Name | Purchase Type 1 | Purchase Notes 1 | Purchase Type 2| Purchase Notes 2  | Purchase Type 3 | Purchase Notes 3
------------ +------+-----------------+------------------+----------------+-------------------+-----------------+------------------
1            | John | Furniture       |TextABC           | Appliance      | TextDEF           | Accessory       | TextGHI
```

**Requirements**:

I can't hard code any of the purchase types or notes because they can change.
I can't determine how many types because it could be 9 or 4 depending on the customer.

How do I add the numbering to the header so that the table can contain up to *x* but those customers that have less than *x* will just have blanks?

Reading through the forum on SQL Pivot, I can't seem to find a way to do this without hard coding it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic TSQL and `PIVOT`:

```
if OBJECT_ID('dbo.test') is null 
    create table dbo.test (CustomerID int , [Name] varchar(50), PurchaseType varchar(50), PurchaseNotes varchar(50))
truncate table dbo.test 

--populate test table
insert into dbo.test values
 (1, 'John','Furniture','TextABC'), (1, 'John','Appliance','TextDEF'), (1, 'John','Accessory','TextGHI')
,(2, 'Mary','Furniture','TextJKL'), (2, 'Mary','Appliance','TextMNO'), (2, 'Mary','Accessory','TextPQR'), (2, 'Mary','New type','TextSTU') 

declare @total         int
declare @counter       int = 1
declare @PurchaseNotes nvarchar(max)='' --holds all the PurchaseNotes column names 
declare @PurchaseType  nvarchar(max)='' --holds all the PurchaseType column names  
declare @Combo         nvarchar(max)='' --holds the combination of PurchaseType and PurchaseNotes for the final SELECT statement
declare @sql           nvarchar(max)='' --contains the TSQL dinamically generated 

--count distinct Purchase Types
select @total = count(distinct [PurchaseType]) from dbo.test 

--build headers
while @counter <= @total
    begin
       set @PurchaseNotes = @PurchaseNotes + ' [PurchaseNotes' + cast(@counter as varchar(max)) + '],'
       set @PurchaseType = @PurchaseType + ' [PurchaseType' + cast(@counter as varchar(max)) + '],'
       set @Combo = @Combo + ' [PurchaseType' + cast(@counter as varchar(max)) + '],'+ ' [PurchaseNotes' + cast(@counter as varchar(max)) + '],'
       set @counter = @counter + 1
    end

set @PurchaseNotes = left(@PurchaseNotes,len(@PurchaseNotes)-1) + ' '
set @PurchaseType = left(@PurchaseType,len(@PurchaseType)-1)+ ' '
set @Combo = left(@Combo,len(@Combo)-1)+ ' '

--create dynamic TSQL query
set @sql = @sql + ' SELECT T.CustomerID, T.[Name],' + @Combo
set @sql = @sql + ' FROM '
set @sql = @sql + ' ( '
set @sql = @sql + '     SELECT [CustomerID],[Name],[PurchaseType],'
set @sql = @sql + '         CONCAT(''PurchaseType'',ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customerid ORDER BY customerid, [Name])) AS COL  '
set @sql = @sql + '     FROM  dbo.test '
set @sql = @sql + ' ) SRC '
set @sql = @sql + ' PIVOT '
set @sql = @sql + ' ( '
set @sql = @sql + '     MAX(PurchaseType) '
set @sql = @sql + '     FOR COL IN (' + @PurchaseType + ') '
set @sql = @sql + ' ) AS T '
set @sql = @sql + ' inner join '
set @sql = @sql + ' ('
set @sql = @sql + '     SELECT * '
set @sql = @sql + '     FROM '
set @sql = @sql + '     ( '
set @sql = @sql + '         SELECT [CustomerID],[Name],[PurchaseNotes],'
set @sql = @sql + '             CONCAT(''PurchaseNotes'',ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customerid ORDER BY customerid, [Name])) AS COL2 '
set @sql = @sql + '         FROM  dbo.test '
set @sql = @sql + '     ) SRC '
set @sql = @sql + '      PIVOT '
set @sql = @sql + '     ( '
set @sql = @sql + '         MAX(PurchaseNotes) '
set @sql = @sql + '         FOR COL2 IN (' + @PurchaseNotes + ') '
set @sql = @sql + '     ) AS PVT2 '
set @sql = @sql + ' ) N'
set @sql = @sql + '  on T.CustomerID = N.CustomerID'

--execute dynamic query
exec (@sql)
```

Input (I added another customer with a new PurchaseType):

[image]

Results:

[image]